# Excel macro to search for text then Popup box if found then display number of times word appears

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me alter this code so that when it finds the word it will also display the number of times the word appears? Thanks!

```
Sub findtext()
'
' findrobot Macro
' Will find the word robot
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+t
'
Dim found As Variant

Set found = Sheets("Email").Cells.find("robot", Sheets("Email").Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlPart)

If (Not found Is Nothing) Then


    'found
    MsgBox "Words Found =" & found, vbOKOnly, "Found"


Else

    'not found
MsgBox "Sorry the text was not found please try again. Macro stopping"

 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You'll probably need to loop with the `.FindNext` method. There should be several examples of how to use that here on StackOverflow. Check them out and you can try to adapt your code, or if you have trouble modifying, just revise your question to show what you found, what you have tried, and explain that it is not working as you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun (and not really stress tested, but seems to work), here is a non-looping version:

```
Sub test()
Dim Number  As Long
Dim str     As String

str = "robot"

Number = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(""" & str & """,A1:AZ6,1)))))")

MsgBox str & " was found " & Number & " times!"

End Sub
```

Be sure to adjust the range in the Evaluate line (currently A1:AZ6) to suit your situation.  Also, I'm pretty sure this will not return the correct results if the word you're looking for appears multiple times in a cell.  I've got to run to a meeting, but if you think that will be the case, I can see if I can sort that out a bit later...

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted it to do!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help.  Good luck with the rest of your project!